# Rails toggling radio button checked with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am making a survey app with possible answers between 1 -5 agree/disagree.

If the user submits the form and has not answered all questions I redirect them back, and am trying to set the correct radio button as checked so they do not lose their existing answers.

i.e if for question 5 they selected 4 as their answer, then I want to set its value to 4.

The problem is the code below is not setting checked='checked' when it should.

```
input id="#{ question.id }-5" name=question.id type='radio' value='5' checked=(params[question.id.to_i.to_s.to_sym] == 5?'checked':false)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
 checked=(params[question.id.to_s] == '5'?'checked':false)
```

The main change is comparing params value to `String '5'` and not `Integer 5` as the params value is a string itself.

Also you do not need to `to_i.to_s.to_sym` , `to_s` should suffice but that was not the issue.